# Firestore exception with Korean language

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

when I use Korean language with Firestore. 
Occur exception like this...

how can I solve it?

FAILED: Read document has key () instead of expected key ().'

*** First throw call stack:

(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001180d81ab __exceptionPreprocess + 171

```
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000011776df41 objc_exception_throw + 48

2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001180dd372 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 98

3   Foundation                          0x0000000117212089 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 193

4   dayView                             0x000000010d69e3ea -[FSTLevelDBRemoteDocumentCache decodedMaybeDocument:withKey:] + 754

5   dayView                             0x000000010d69ddcf -[FSTLevelDBRemoteDocumentCache documentsMatchingQuery:] + 488

6   dayView                             0x000000010d69ec69 -[FSTLocalDocumentsView documentsMatchingCollectionQuery:] + 171

7   dayView                             0x000000010d69ea6f -[FSTLocalDocumentsView documentsMatchingQuery:] + 210

8   dayView                             0x000000010d6a3f01 -[FSTLocalStore executeQuery:] + 79

9   dayView                             0x000000010d68946c -[FSTSyncEngine listenToQuery:] + 273

10  dayView                             0x000000010d68132d -[FSTEventManager addListener:] + 469

11  dayView                             0x000000010d6831da __64-[FSTFirestoreClient listenToQuery:options:viewSnapshotHandler:]_block_invoke + 62

12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001196ca3f7 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12

13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001196cb43c _dispatch_client_callout + 8

14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001196d395b _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 1162

15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001196d42df _dispatch_queue_invoke + 336

16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001196d007d _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 733

17  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001196d71f9 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 772

18  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001196d6e97 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 132

19  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000119b931ca _pthread_wqthread + 1387

20  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000119b92c4d start_wqthread + 13
```

)

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: You should format the exception out so that it is easier to read

Comment: To solve it you should include the code that throws the error. That can sometimes be done by inserting a breakpoint in your code and stepping through one line at a time until the error occurs. Please review the following two guides on asking questions: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)